# Save YUI2 DataTable content to $_POST

Tags: php, post, datatable, yui2

I'm populating a YUI2 DataTable from a database (in PHP). Now the user should make changes to the DataTable. These changes should be saved to $_POST so they can be saved to the database again.

My problem: The only way to put variables into post seems to be input elements in a form. But the DataTable contains no input elements, it is text that will spawn a JavaScript entry field onClick.

Anyone know a way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering the same thing, you can access the data from the DataTable per getRecord, with the help of getCount and getData functions.